# Low average call duration

Tags: sip, voip

My Mera VoIP Transit Softswitch (MVTS) shows very low ACD (about 0.3 min) for several directions (route groups) at peak hours. Looking for factors causing low ACD, I foung this topic: http://support.sippysoft.com/support/discussions/topics/3000137333, but all mentioned parameters seem to be normal. There is another strange thing also. As  seen at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQtYV.png) graph, there are about 10 lines occupied for each real call. I guess these problems are related somehow, though not sure yet.
What can cause such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the followings:

1. SIP trunk quality
   Your trunk or service providers might have quality issues to these directions. You can easily test this by sending the same traffic in the same time to some other carriers.
2. Low call quality under high load
   You can easily verify this by just making a call during peak time and hear it yourself.
3. Some other factor causing call drop in similar circumstances.
   Causes might include maximum supported channels, billing cut-off or others.
   You should grab a statistics about disconnect codes and compare it to off-peak time or to other directions